# Symfony 2.0 Dynamically form inside an another form factory

Tags: forms, symfony, collections

I'm trying to develop a bet web page. I have an entity "Apuesta" (bet) and an entity "Partido" (match).
An "Apuesta" have a collection of Partido (in the attr $Partidos) and the getter getPartidos() which return the collection.
A "Partido" have a type (0 or 1), which specify the fields of his form depending on this value.

What I want to get is to include the "Partido" Form into the "Apuesta" Form, but I want that the "Partido" knows itself to render his own Form depending on the $Type value. Obviously, the "Apuesta" is created in the database with his own "Partidos".

My code is:

```
    class ApuestaForm extends AbstractType{

    public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
    {

        $p = $builder->getData()->getPartidos();


        $builder->add('Jornada')
                ->add('Partidos', 'collection', array('type' => new PartidoForm()));

    }

    public function getName(){
        return 'ApuestaForm';
    }

    public function getDefaultOptions(array $options)
    {
        return array(
            'data_class' => 'A\ApuestaBundle\Entity\Apuesta',
        );
    }

}
```

#

```
class PartidoForm extends AbstractType
{

    public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
    {
        **$tipo;
       //$partido = $builder->getData();
       //$tipo = $partido->getTipo();

       $builder->add('Local')
               ->add('Visitante')
               ->add('Tipo')
               ->add('Jornada');
               if ($tipo == 1){ 
                   $builder->add('some field 1')
               }
               else{ 
                   $builder->add('some field 2')
               }

    }

    public function getName(){
        return 'PartidoForm';
    }

    public function getDefaultOptions(array $options)
    {
        return array(
            'data_class' => 'A\ApuestaBundle\Entity\Partido',
        );
    }

}
```

This way, an "Apuesta" render automatically his own "Partidos" and each "Partido" should know if his $Type is 1 or 0. The problem is that $builder->getData() doesn't get the "Partido" entity, but also a null.

Another way I thought to do it was to do a contruct with an entity param "Partido", but the problem is that the "Apuesta" Form render a collection of "Partido", so I can't pass a single object "Partido", but also a collection.

I tried not to use Form events, because it is a very simple Form.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

To pass parameters to the form, you have to do the following:

```
class PartidoForm extends AbstractType
{

public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
{
   // $tipo;
   $tipo = $options['tipo']; // <<---- Get "tipo" from the options array
   //$partido = $builder->getData();
   //$tipo = $partido->getTipo();

   $builder->add('Local')
           ->add('Visitante')
           ->add('Tipo')
           ->add('Jornada');
           if ($tipo == 1){ 
               $builder->add('some field 1')
           }
           else{ 
               $builder->add('some field 2')
           }

}

public function getName(){
    return 'PartidoForm';
}

public function getDefaultOptions(array $options)
{
    return array(
        'data_class' => 'A\ApuestaBundle\Entity\Partido',
        'tipo'     => null,** // Set a default null value, or whatever value you want as default
    );
}
```

}

Now, the Partido Form Type accepts the parameter tipo, so when you call it...

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
{

    $p = $builder->getData()->getPartidos();


    $builder->add('Jornada')
            ->add('Partidos', 'collection', array(
                      'type' => new PartidoForm()
                      'options' => array('tipo' => 1)
            )
    );

}
```

Of course you can do the same thing in the  Jornada entity to fetch an option from the controller (fetch it from the options array, and don't forget to add it as an option).

If you want to pass the parameter in the controller, use something like this:

```
$form = $this->createForm(new JornadaType(), $jornada, array('tipo' => $tipo));
```

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't work. 

in : 

$builder->add('Jornada') 
         ->add('Partidos', 'collection', 
           array( 'type' => newPartidoForm() 'options' => array('tipo' => 1) ) ); 

I should pass the $Type of each Partido inside the collection of Partidos. So, dinamically, when rendering the form, each Partido inside Partidos, should get his $type to render itself. thanks!

Comment: I think you have another problem there. You know that this is all generated before showing the website to the user, so this would only work when you edit the form, when the info is displayed. When you create a new entity, nothing would show up since "tipo" is null. You could try to do it with Jquery dynamically on the loaded page (I would suggest doing that). If that's not what you need, please tell me what does the tipo/type means (for the entity), and why would you add one field or another.

Comment: The entities "Apuesta" is created, with some "Partido" created too, in a relation OneToMany.
The $Typo of "Partido" means how you have to especify the result of the match. If $Typo is 1, yo have to put a numeric value (for example 0-2), but if the $Typo is 2, you have to check only the winner ( 1 x 2 ).
This way I was triying to created an "Apuesta" (bet) with some "Partidos" (matches), and depending the $Typo value, let the user put a numeric result or not.
So the "Partido" Form, should know what is his $typo automatically for when the "Apuesta" Form render his collection of "Partido".

Comment: You have two choices then, 1) Create Partido, save it, and then create apuestas for each partido (and having the $tipo parameter from the Partido entity), or 2) In the creation form of Partido, add as many apuestas as you want, and check via javascript (or jQuery) the tipo selected and then make the field numeric or not. I think that the better choice is numer (1) because you need to create a match (Partido) to make Bets (Apuestas) on it.